# How to implement a timeout for a process in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timeout

I want to implement a timeout for a process, if it takes more than X amount of seconds, I want it to stop and execute the return statement regardless.
In my real world use I would be calling a REST API, apiCallController() represents the Controller.

With what I've tried below everything just keeps on executing regardless.

How do I pull this off?

EDIT: If what I'm trying to achieve works, the long running task won't complete which means that the line

```
System.out.println("End http/SSH stuff...");
```

will never print, and this line

```
response = "Call successful...";
```

will not be executed either, leaving the response variable as originally initialized

```
String response = "Call aborted...";
```

But I still need to return the response after the timeout

I've been testing in this Java fiddle (you can just paste the code): https://javafiddle.leaningtech.com/

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String response = apiCallController();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    
    public static String apiCallController() {
        System.out.println("creepy...\n");
        int timeoutSeconds = 2;
        int longRunningTaskDurationSeconds = 5;
        String response = "Call aborted...";

        try 
        {
            new Timer().schedule( 
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Timeout reached, aborting... (This is where I want everything to stop without killing JVM/Tomcat)");
                        // System.exit(0); This guy shut tomcat down x_X
                        return;
                    }
                }, 
                timeoutSeconds * 1000
            );
            
            System.out.println("Start http/SSH stuff...");
            Thread.sleep(longRunningTaskDurationSeconds * 1000);
            System.out.println("End http/SSH stuff...");
            
            response = "Call successful...";

        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("\npasta...");
        
        return "\n" + response;
    }
    
  }
```

EDIT 2: From the accepted answer, I just refactored a touch:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("creepy...\n\n");

        String response = apiCallController();
        System.out.println(response);

        System.out.println("\n\npasta...");
        
    }
    
    public static String apiCallController() {
        String response = "Stuff TIMED out...";
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Callable<String> r = () -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Start http/SSH stuff...");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                System.out.println("End http/SSH stuff...");
                return "Stuff COMPLETED successfully...";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        };
        Future<String> task = executor.submit(r);

        try {
            response = task.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch(InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            task.cancel(true);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Need to shutdown executor (think of it is master thread here)
        // You may want to control this behaviour outside of this function call
        executor.shutdown();

        return "\n" + response;
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: What is `timeout*1000` ?

Comment: I'm converting seconds into milliseconds.

Comment: Have you seen [Asynchronous timeouts with CompletableFutures in Java 8 and Java 9](http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html)?

Comment: By the way, you can replace `timeoutSeconds * 1000` with the more obvious `Duration.ofSeconds( timeoutSeconds ).toMillis()`. Even better, change the type of `timeoutSeconds ` to be a `Duration` object named `timeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is finished after printing to console but your timer is waiting for more task, hence still running and because it is still running the `main` function won't exit.

If you don't have further task you need to `cancel` your timer.

```
try
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("Timeout reached, aborting... (This is where I want everything to stop without killing JVM/Tomcat)");
                        }
                    },
                    timeoutSeconds * 1000
            );

            System.out.println("Start http/SSH stuff...");
            Thread.sleep(longRunningTaskDurationSeconds * 1000);
            System.out.println("End http/SSH stuff...");

            response = "Call successful...";

            timer.cancel();

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("\npasta...");

        return "\n" + response;
```

**Edit**

Since the question is updated with real use case, I am adding a edit here to suggest an answer for that use case (Earlier part may not relevant to the question now).

This is my solution to your problem, have a look. I have used `Future` and `ScheduledExecutorService` to achieve it.

```
public static String apiCallController() {
        System.out.println("creepy...\n");
        
        String response = "Call aborted...";

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        Callable<String> r = () -> {
            try {
                // To mimick the actual call
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                System.out.println("call successful...");
                return "Some response";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Timeout reached, aborting... (This is where I want everything to stop without killing JVM/Tomcat)");
                throw e;
            }
        };

        Future<String> task = executor.submit(r);

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Start http/SSH stuff...");
            
            //Let's just wait for 3 secs for response to arrive
            response = task.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            System.out.println("End http/SSH stuff...");

            response = "Call successful...";

        }
        catch(InterruptedException | TimeoutException e)
        {
            // cancelling a task, either it was interrupted (sleep call can be interrupted) or its timeout
            task.cancel(true);
        }catch (ExecutionException e) {
            //Something went wrong horribly
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("\npasta...");

        // Need to shutdown executor (think of it is master thread here)
        // You may want to control this behaviour outside of this function call
        executor.shutdown();

        return "\n" + response;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to prevent these lines from not executing: System.out.println("End http/SSH stuff..."); response = "Call successful...";. They still do with your solution.

Comment: Please update your question with this information, thanks.